# How to access to field when iterating over 2d array in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

currently I'm learning Thymeleaf. I want to show user simple grid contaning buttons and values. The problem is I can't access to variable of Java object during iterate. The 2d array consists of SeatsSeances objects.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class SeatsSeance {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer seatId;
    private Integer seanceId;
    private SeatState state;
}
```

```
<table>
<tr th:each="row: ${seatSeances}">
<td th:each="place: ${row}">

<input type="button" th:text="${place.state.name()}"> //not working
<input type="button" th:text="${place.getState().name()}"> //not working

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I'm simply try `th:text="${place.state.name()}"` there is an error:

```
Thu Aug 20 09:38:54 CEST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/buyticket.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/buyticket.html]")
```

What I'm doing wrong? What should be inside `<td th:each>` tag?

**Updated 1**

SeatSeance class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class SeatsSeance {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer seatId;
    private Integer seanceId;
    private SeatState state;
}
```

SeatState class

```
public enum SeatState { RESERVED, ORDERED, FREE
}
```

IDE allows me to use all fields in HTML so the problem is not in accessibility. What is more, there is no problem to use

`<input type="button" th:text="${place}">`

The problem starts when I want to display one field of the object. I can't do that despite getters and setters

**Update 2**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the full log of the error?.

Comment: How to do that if logs are too long? It seems to me that the following may be the most important

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/buyticket.html]")

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null

Comment: There you have it! __"Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null"__. That means Thymeleaf is trying to render the `id` attribute of an object that is null. 
Is the HTML complete? Are you trying to process the `id` attribute somewhere?

Comment: Can you add your SeatState.java class?

Comment: Also check if your name()  method in SeatState.java has a public access modifier

Comment: I added update in the first post to make it clearer. In my opinion there is no problem in accessibility

Comment: Are you sure that every SeatsSeance record has not null SeatStates? Because according to the stacktrace the problem is that you try to call methods over a null object.

Comment: Please take a look a update 2 in the first post - I've added two screenshots. 
In the first one you can see that there are objects in the array because they can be displayed in `<span>`. On the second you can see that Intellij recognizes the fields of this class. Unfortunately, when I want to refer to it, I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide getter/setter for all atributes of your class. If you use Spring Lombok, you need to add `@Getter @Setter` tags.

Comment: I have all getters and setters. SeatsSeances class already have annotation
`@Data`
which contains:
`@Getter , @Setter , @ToString , @EqualsAndHashCode and @RequiredArgsConstructor` annotations